# Find a list of recent iCloud backups

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I want to see the list of the recent iCloud backups my phone has made. By going into Settings->iCloud->Backups I can see that my most recent backup was at 1:04am, but **I would like to see all of my recent backups!** This can't be seen on iCloud.com, nor on my iPhone.

The only place I know I can see all the backups listed is after a factory reset, as in the image below, but I really would not like to do a factory reset.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can't. There's no way to view this either on an iPhone/iPad or over at iCloud.com. If you ever need to access a list of backups, contact apple at https://getsupport.apple.com.